# C# DllImport - Call a function that returns an struct

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I am working in C# and I need to call a function in a C++ dll library.  This function returns a struct but I can´t get anything.

This is the function I need to call and the struct that returns in C++ library:

```
ATHENA_API _DEVICE_INFO* __stdcall  GetDeviceInfoKeepConnection(_DEVICE_INFO* pDeviceInfo);

typedef struct TD_DEVICE_INFO{
   TCHAR  chDeviceName[256];
   int   nCommPort;
   int   nECGPos;
   int   nNumberOfChannel;
   int   nESUType;
   int   nTymestampType;
   int   nDeviceHandle;
   TCHAR  chDeviceID[260];
}_DEVICE_INFO;
```

This is my C# code trying to call the function:

```
[DllImport(@"\BAlertSDK\ABM_Athena.dll")]
static extern _DEVICE_INFO GetDeviceInfoKeepConnection(_DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct _DEVICE_INFO
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string chDeviceName;
    public int nCommPort;
    public int nECGPos;
    public int nNumberOfChannel;
    public int nESUType;
    public int nTymestampType;
    public int nDeviceHandle;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string chDeviceID;
}

void Test_Click()
{
    _DEVICE_INFO d = new _DEVICE_INFO();
    _DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo = GetDeviceInfoKeepConnection(d);
}
```

The only I can get is an empty _DEVICE_INFO object.  I think my problem is that I am not defining correctly the DEVICE INFO struct.

I have never worked with dll´s to this level.  Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the C++ struct, you should be using Windows types such as `LONG`, and not `int`.  The reason is that `int` is not guaranteed to be 4 bytes.

Comment: Also, if you have any doubts about how to marshall certain types, you can look at the Windows API to find similar constructs, and how [pinvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/LOGFONT.html) handles them.  The example I linked to handles the `LOGFONT` struct between `C++` and C#.

Comment: The c++ code is not mine.  I can´t modify it.  It´s a comercial dll.  Thanks!

Comment: If it's not your code, then somewhere you should have a `static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(LONG));` somewhere, so that you are not attempting to build an application that will not work.

Comment: First is tchar chDeviceName, so even if there would be a problem with size of int this field should be filed... Native method expects to get pointer to structure not value... Maybe you should use ref and check if fields would be filed in passed by ref structure

Comment: Thanks!  How I should implement ref?
Sorry for my ignorance...

Comment: First, declare GetDeviceInfoKeepConnection deviceInfo parameter as ref and return value as IntPtr. Then call it like this `var output = Marshal.PtrToStructure<_DEVICE_INFO>(GetDeviceInfoKeepConnection(ref input);`

Comment: This code should always crash, be sure to remove try/catch from the test code.  The parameter needs `ref`, the return type must be `IntPtr` and converted with Marshal.PtrToStructure().  The struct should have `CharSet`, good odds that you need CharSet.Unicode.  And I suspect you need to set the chDeviceName field before the call to specify the device you want info for.  Call the owner of the DLL for help.

Comment: "function that returns an struct". This function returns a pointer to a struct. Entirely different concept. As Hans says, speak to the developer or even read their documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all!!  The problem has solved with this:

Parameter pass by reference and struct charset Unicode.

Comment: `ATHENA_API int __stdcall GetEEGChannelsInfo( _EEGCHANNELS_INFO & stEEGChannelsInfo);` If this is the function you are trying to call from C#, you should not use C++ reference parameters (`&`) in exported function calls.  A C++ reference is only to be used within C++ applications, and is only known by the C++ language.

Comment: Ok Paul, in this case (no by reference), what is the correct way to declare the method?:
`[DllImport(dll)] static extern int GetEEGChannelsInfo(_EEGCHANNELS_INFO e);`
or
`[DllImport(dll)] static extern int GetEEGChannelsInfo(IntPtr e);`

Comment: As mentioned in the main comments, refer to how the Windows API marshall's structs using the pinvoke link.  An example is `LOGFONT` and `CreateFontIndirect`:  [CreateFontIndirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfontindirecta).  Here is the [pinvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/CreateFontIndirect.html).  Mimic what you are trying to do with how it is being done with CreateFontIndirect.  A `LOGFONT` needs to be passed between C++ and .NET (C# in you case), and you see how it is done.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that the function GetDeviceInfoKeepConnection returns a pointer to _DEVICE_INFO struct. So, in your C# code, you need to change the definition of the function to:

[DllImport(@"\BAlertSDK\ABM_Athena.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDeviceInfoKeepConnection(IntPtr deviceInfo);

And then you can access the struct data like this:

```
void Test_Click()
{
_DEVICE_INFO d = new _DEVICE_INFO();
IntPtr pDeviceInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(d));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(d, pDeviceInfo, false);
IntPtr deviceInfo = GetDeviceInfoKeepConnection(pDeviceInfo);
_DEVICE_INFO result = (_DEVICE_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(deviceInfo, typeof(_DEVICE_INFO));
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pDeviceInfo);
}
```

Note that, to ensure that the memory is cleaned up after use, you should use the Marshal.FreeHGlobal method to free the memory that was allocated by Marshal.AllocHGlobal.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have tried your solution and "result" is an _DEVICE_INFO empty object...

Comment: Do you think the C# definition of _DEVICE_INFO struct is correct?